# Is there any downside to using localized characters in urls?

Tags: localization, url

I'm working on a site with both english and spanish locales. Crafts localization features have been awesome so far, and I've been embracing Craft's ability to easily localize URLs.

For example, if I have a section on conservation, the english url would be:

```
www.mysite.com/conservation
```

And the spanish one would be:

```
www.mysite.com/es/conservación
```

Am I going to run into any technical issues by allowing accented characters in my urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is technically nothing wrong with using them in a URI since they are valid URI characters.  Even multi-byte characters (Chinese, Korean, Japanese, etc.) are valid in the URI (i.e. domain.com/漢字漢字).

However, some people have requested that they not be allowed in the slug, so for the upcoming 2.2 release, we've added a config setting where you can disable the behavior and multi-byte characters are stripped and high-ASCII characters like ó are swapped with their low-ASCII counterparts (o).

I can't speak to any other non-technical reasons why they might not want to be used (SEO, etc.).